# How to redirect output of aplay to ekiga voip softphone?

Tags: audio, alsa, ekiga

I want to play something by aplay and i want to this sound appear on ekiga input device as on microphone. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found that on linux you can use snd_aloop module, that creates virtual sound card in system. Under the link details:

http://blog.getreu.net/projects/snd-aloop-device/